# Ignore Sphinx autodoc warnings for rtype values

Tags: python-sphinx, autodoc

Right now autodoc seems to throw warnings for any `rtype` value that is not just an object type (a class instance, int, list, dictionary, etc).  So a return value such as "list of tuples" will throw a warning. Is there any way to ignore these warnings (either individually or on the whole)? I don't want to ignore the whole file, just those specific warnings.

An example of this warning might be something like:

```
/path/to/code.py:docstring of path.to.code.method:: WARNING: py:class reference target not found: list of tuples
```

And in some cases, I'm seeing errors for objects that I know are legit classes imported in the code like:

```
/path/to/code.py:docstring of path.to.code.method:: WARNING: py:class reference target not found: Response
```

In that example, "Response" is part of rest_framework.response, so it's a pretty commonly used class object.

These warnings happen anytime I do a fresh make docs.  It's not clear to be that it can be reproduced in another environment.

Comment: What is the warning message? How can we reproduce the problem?

Comment: You need to install any packages that are referenced in your virtual environment where Sphinx is also installed.

Comment: Do you have `nitpicky = True` in conf.py? See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-nitpicky

Comment: Again: how can we reproduce this? See [mcve].

Comment: If you have a solution, please post it as an Answer. Do not post solutions by editing the Question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here was that the classes in question were not in a toctree, so were not part of the docs. Basically, autodocs wants to be able to link to classes mentioned in type variables. If it can't do that, it will throw an error saying "I have no idea what "Response" is (or whatever the class happens to be that you return). Not an error, because it assumed you're right, but a warning that it can't find it. So the solution here was to create an index.rst that included the class, then a Response.rst (for example) including the relative path to the class. Below is an example of this process.  It assumes that Response is in a rest.py.

```
error:  /path/to/code.py:docstring of the.code.rest.GetAccount.get:: WARNING: py:class reference target not found: Response
```

In my case, this needed the following:

1. add a line item for `response` to modules/code/rest.rst
2. add response.rst in the same directory
3. include the line `.. automodule:: code.rest.Response

Then delete and rebuild docs and it should be good to go.